# Find characters that have 2 or more *

Tags: regex, linux, grep, posix

If I want to show the lines that  have  2 or more times the character this  `*`.

```
egrep '*{2}' file
```

Comment: `*` is a special character in `regex`. In order to represent itself you have to escape it (i.e. `\*`). Two or more consecutive occurrences is `{2,}` but if they don't need to be consecutive then `{...}` doesn't help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
grep '\*[^*]*\*' file
```

The `\*[^*]*\*` pattern will match a line that has `*`, then any 0+ chars other than `*` and then a `*`.

See [online demo](https://ideone.com/NiYFVE):

```
s="*one
*two*
.... *three* and more text here**"
grep '\*[^*]*\*' <<< "$s"
```

Output:

```
*two*
.... *three* and more text here**
```

Comment: @maikl Yes, you may use the same with egrep, see [this online demo](https://ideone.com/FGEeHh).

Comment: @maikl Yes, see the demo link in my previous comment.

Comment: I think you could simplify it with `grep '\**\*'`, not?

Comment: @Quasímodo `\**\*` matches a string with 1 or more asterisks because `\**` matches 0+ asterisks and then `\*` matches 1 asterisk.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Sorry, I meant `grep '\*.*\*'`.

Comment: @Quasímodo Right, but it is a bit "heavier" due to `.*`. I prefer a negated bracket expression here since it is computationally less hard.